# How Can I specialize a std map for multiple key types?

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I have a subclass of std::map

```
template<class ValueT>
FancyKeyMap
    : public std::map<FancyKey,ValueT, FancyKey::Less>
{
     ...
public:
     inline iterator find(FancyKeyArg key)
     {
         return(std::map<FancyKey,ValueT,
                FancyKey::Less>::find(FancyKeyArg.makeKeyRef()));
     }  
};
```

this works fine, (dont ask why I don't want to use some implicint conversion, this causes too many ambiguous overloads also a full conversion in this case is expensive :)

anyway it woudl be nice if the above could be a specialization of std::map where any

```
std::map<FancyKey,ValueT> fancymap;
```

woudl do the same thing as

```
FancyKeyMap<ValueT> fancyMap;
```

can one do this type of specialization?

---

Ok just tried a partial specialization:

```
namespace std {

template<class ValT, class CompareT=FancyKey::Less, 
         class AllocT=allocator<pair<const FancyKey,ValT> > >
    class map<FancyKey, ValT, CompareT, AllocT>
{
     ....
};

}
```

I get this error:

"default arguments not allowed on a partial specialization"

but to make it act like std::map it needs to have the "inherited" default args *and* allow them to be overridden.  Next step is that possible ?

I did see a suggestion for having a searchable template FAQ it does seem this is a very common question ;^>

Comment: Why do you have `FancyKeyMap`?

Comment: In C++0x you can say `tempate <typename T> using FancyKeyMap = std::map<FancyKey, T>;`.

Comment: I hope you're aware that inheriting from STL containers is generally considered bad practice because they don't have virtual destructors. You can get away with it if you don't add data members to your class but it's probably best to use composition instead.

Comment: @Alex: Adding data members has nothing to do with it. `struct f : std::map<int, int> {}; std::map<int, int>* x = new f; delete x;` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a lot of trouble to avoid typing `makeKeyRef()` (in `find` calls) and being more explicit about the intent at the same time. Have you considered just doing the extra typing and making your intent clear to future maintainers?

Also, since standard containers don't have virtual destructors unless you non-publicly inherit you're opening yourself up to undefined behavior when one is destroyed by base class pointer sometime.

Comment: As the subclass would only contain an inline cast for a stack argument the destructor thing isn't an issue.  The main purpose is so one can write code as if it was a std::map and have it select the proper compare reference and do the key reference cast depending on the key type, then dink with the header to alter a centralized definition behavior (factored out) without having to change all the code.  Or if one switches the key type likewise.    What I want is a specialization for the key type that can specify the default compare type, and override some of the methods.